# Binding control name problem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have in the mainwindow this code:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tc" Margin="0" SelectedIndex="0">
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1" Width="150"
             IsSelected="false">
        <!--<TextBox Width="200" Height="200"/>-->
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

i have a mainwindowviewmodel and i want it to bind to the controltab name which is tc:

```
private void AddTab_Execute(object parm)
{
    s = s + 1;
    TabItem Item = new TabItem();
    Item.Width = 150;
    Item.Header = "Tab " + s;
    tc.Items.Add(Item);
}
```

he doesn't recognize tc
what do i have to do ?

Comment: Is the mainwindowviewmodel code behind of mainwindow, i.e. is it mainwindow.xaml.cs? Where's the binding in your code?

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), but it would be easier if you had one. You should not need to reference controls like the `TabControl` in the view-model.

Bind the `ItemsSource` of the the TabControl to an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), then you just need to add items to that collection. Use the [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) (header) and [`ContentTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.contenttemplate.aspx) (tab item content) to create the tabs from the items in the collecton dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, be careful with how you are using the word "bind". That has a particular meaning which is not what you are doing in your example. To see what binding actually means, check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

You cannot access controls in your UI from your viewmodel. What you should be doing is binding the ItemsSource of the TabControl to a collection in the viewmodel. You can create  [DataTemplateSelectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) and use them for the TabControl's [ContentTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx) and [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) if you want to select different templates depending on the item which is bound to each TabItem.